# Connecting hawtio with camel app in karaf

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, karaf, hawtio, spring-camel

I have hawtio connected to jlokia agent on karaf 4.2.1. But i dont understand how can i connect hawtio to camel route(Spring dsl) deployed in karaf or some bundle? Maybe i need set jlokia agent in camelContext? 

Help me please with any suggest.

Jolokia agent in karaf:

```
{"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"agent":"1.6.0","protocol":"7.2","config":{"listenForHttpService":"true","authIgnoreCerts":"false","agentId":"10.183.173.218-4519-15cbbe6e-osgi","debug":"false","agentType":"servlet","policyLocation":"classpath:\/jolokia-access.xml","agentContext":"\/jolokia","serializeException":"false","mimeType":"text\/plain","dispatcherClasses":"org.jolokia.http.Jsr160ProxyNotEnabledByDefaultAnymoreDispatcher","authMode":"basic","streaming":"true","canonicalNaming":"true","historyMaxEntries":"10","allowErrorDetails":"true","allowDnsReverseLookup":"true","realm":"jolokia","includeStackTrace":"true","useRestrictorService":"false","debugMaxEntries":"100"},"info":{"product":"felix","vendor":"Apache","version":"5.6.10"}},"timestamp":1543929143,"status":200}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy some Camel routes on Karaf to get the Hawtio Camel tab visible on Hawtio console. You don't need to connect Hawtio to a remote Jolokia agent. Hawtio can be installed on Karaf as follows:

```
feature:repo-add hawtio 2.3.0
feature:install hawtio
```